# URL Trimming issue in SharePoint Online Hyperlink Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, hyperlink, list-column

While adding hyperlinks in SharePoint Hyperlink column, few links are getting trimmed.

As default it should accept 255 characters and the URL that I used not exceeded this limit.

Comment: Hyperlink column has limit of 255 characters. If possible, can you show us the link you are trying to add to hyperlink column?

Comment: sorry it's  a sensitive data, but it's a file URL Stored in Document library